# ActionFilterAttribute - retrieve querystring .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a FilterAttribute and would like to read from the query string.

I receive the error as shown below. According to some blog entries this is an acceptable practice https://jacstech.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/retrieving-parameters-from-the-query-string-in-the-url-in-net/ but am thinking this has change in .net core 2.2

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Controller is Controller controller)
        {
            ...
            controller.ViewBag.lnsalesquotationnumber = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["lnsalesquotationnumber"];  
        }

    }
```

ERPFilter.cs(32,61): error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'QueryString' [C:\Projects\FarrisCosting\Projects.csproj]

Comment: Use `Request.Query[...]` instead of `Request.QueryString[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

I have get QueryString value this using code

```
public class TestFilter : IActionFilter
{
   public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
   {

   }

   public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
      var queryStringValue= context.HttpContext.Request.Query["QueryStringKey"].ToString();
   }
}
```